# Can't Install Mysql Server on Windows 10

Tags: mysql

I could really use some help here.

So I am trying to install Mysql onto my Widows - 64 bit machine and I am having a lot of frustrating issues.

All of the other components through the MySQL installer will download and install fine but every single time the server fails. I have tried different variants of Microsoft Visual from 2013 , 2015 and 2017 and none of them change anything, it always fails. I have looked all over the internet for a fix and have found nothing that changes the result of it failing.

This is incredibly frustrating and I will answer any questions you have to help me solve this. I am not well versed in this so please understand.

I have tried many different versions of the server as well.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZETwB.png)

This is some of what the details say

```
1: File: errmsg.sys,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\czech\,  Size: 278822
1: File: errmsg.sys,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\danish\,  Size: 278822
1: File: dictionary.txt,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\,  Size: 25575
1: File: errmsg.sys,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\dutch\,  Size: 279842
1: File: errmsg.sys,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\english\,  Size: 278063
1: File: errmsg-utf8.txt,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\,  Size: 860075
1: File: errmsg.sys,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\estonian\,  Size: 278327
1: File: errmsg.sys,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\french\,  Size: 279470
1: File: errmsg.sys,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\german\,  Size: 285694
1: File: errmsg.sys,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\greek\,  Size: 284854
1: File: errmsg.sys,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\hungarian\,  Size: 278704
1: File: innodb_memcached_config.sql,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\,  Size: 3999
1: File: errmsg.sys,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\italian\,  Size: 279833
1: File: errmsg.sys,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\japanese\,  Size: 285509
1: File: errmsg.sys,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\korean\,  Size: 281103
1: File: errmsg.sys,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\norwegian\,  Size: 278133
1: File: errmsg.sys,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\norwegian-ny\,  Size: 278186
1: File: errmsg.sys,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\polish\,  Size: 278992
1: File: errmsg.sys,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\portuguese\,  Size: 281023
1: File: errmsg.sys,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\romanian\,  Size: 279775
1: File: errmsg.sys,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\russian\,  Size: 293338
1: File: errmsg.sys,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\serbian\,  Size: 280444
1: File: errmsg.sys,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\slovak\,  Size: 278589
1: File: errmsg.sys,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\spanish\,  Size: 279717
1: File: errmsg.sys,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\swedish\,  Size: 278916
1: File: errmsg.sys,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\ukrainian\,  Size: 287912
1: Action 1:04:17: CreateShortcuts. Creating shortcuts
1: Shortcut: icon.ico
1: Shortcut: Icon.MysqlCmdShell
1: Shortcut: rpxm3ds_|MySQL 8.0 Command Line Client
1: Shortcut: 7ejegqmo|MySQL 8.0 Command Line Client - Unicode
1: Action 1:04:17: WriteRegistryValues. Writing system registry values
1: Key: \SOFTWARE\MySQL AB\MySQL Server 8.0, Name: Location, Value: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\
1: Key: \SOFTWARE\MySQL AB\MySQL Server 8.0, Name: Version, Value: 8.0.14
1: Key: \SOFTWARE\MySQL AB\MySQL Server 8.0, Name: DataLocation, Value: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\
1: Key: \SOFTWARE\MySQL AB\MySQL Server 8.0, Name: , Value: 
1: Key: \Console\MySQL 8.0 Command Line Client - Unicode, Name: FaceName, Value: Lucida Console
1: Key: \Console\MySQL 8.0 Command Line Client - Unicode, Name: FontWeight, Value: #400
1: Key: \Console\MySQL 8.0 Command Line Client - Unicode, Name: , Value: 
1: Key: \Software\MySQL AB\MySQL Server 8.0, Name: installed, Value: #1
1: Action 1:04:17: ExecSecureObjects. 
1: Action 1:04:17: Rollback. Rolling back action:
1: ExecSecureObjects
1: Writing system registry values
1: Creating shortcuts
1: Copying new files
1: Creating folders
1: Updating component registration
1: 1: MySQL Server 8.0 2: {501EBAC1-FA27-4B8F-96E9-1EABA0AE6492} 3: 3 
1: The action 'Install' for product 'MySQL Server 8.0.14' failed.
```

Comment: Exact same thing happening to me on Windows 10 with MySQL Server 8.0 too. I tried all 3 GA versions and get the same issue with all of them. As far as I can tell there isn't even an error message, just "failed."

Answer (score 0):

When you select the server in the installer, expand the list of sub-components in the panel on the right and untick "Server Data Files".  This worked perfectly on my laptop without needing to uninstall / clean up.